# Baking every object with physics by script

Tags: python, baking, command-line

I am trying to create a set of scripts with bpy that render a project automatically from the console command line, and I have created them.

But before rendering, I want it to actually bake everything that has some physics that need baking. So basically the user executes the script, and it does the process needed to bake all objects with physics that need baking  automatically.

But I am kind of in a dead end now, since I don't really know how to approach this.

Maybe you guys can show me some light here.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit .I don't understand what you are trying to convey!

Comment: Ok, to put it simply, what I am trying to achieve here is a script that renders a blend project. Like if you press F12 or ctrl + F12 in the Blender GUI. I want the output to be correct obviously, so I need to take care of different things like baking. Making a script that gives Blender the order to render is easy, but if you want the script to be complete with options things get a little muddy. Thanks!